# Shortest path algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, weighted

I have questions about an optimal algorithm problem on a weighted graph. I am given an edgelist with weights, a list with savepoints, a starte- and end- node and the max distance for a step. 
The output should be a list of savepoints, which are accessible in one step from starting- and end- node.

I thought of some kind of dijkstra's algorithm from each point of the list of savepoints.

I'm not sure if that's a good idea, since if I have many savepoints I calculate a lot of paths multiple times. Every idea/help is welcome!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do dijkstra from both start and end nodes. As you traverse the graph keep track of the save points you see up until you reach a node which has a total cost greater than the step size.

Comment: Oh that sounds far better! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the condition that a weight cannot be negative, otherwise the problem becomes very intractable. Otherwise it's just a breadth first search, with marking the distance for every visited node. So you don't revisit a node is a previous move has visited it earlier at lower cost.

You keep a priority queue of all active nodes, so you are checking the lowest cost node each time. The priority queue is in fact the hardest part to get right. If you check the A* algorithm for my binary image library https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/binaryimagelibrary you can take the priority queue for there. A* over a maze is very similar to shortest path over a graph, but you don't have a heuristic because you must have the exact shortest path, and instead of 4 / 8 edges per tile, you have nodes with arbitrary numbers of connections.

Comment: Thanks, I can see the parallels! Sorry, I didn't say that but the weights are all postive, makes it a lot easier.